# SO Careers zip code search ignores distance

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

I performed a SO Careers search for postings within 60 miles of 60051.  This worked up through last week, but now I get results from New York, Florida, and parts further-flung.  What broke?

Comment: It appears that place name searches work fine -- if I type "McHenry" in the box, I get the results I expect.  I will edit the post to reflect that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be resolved – we were parsing zipcode-only locations incorrectly.

http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs?location=60051